# Rotating verticies created by a geometry shader

Tags: c++, opengl, rotation, glsl, geometry-shader

I am trying to generate a cube from 6 points (each point representing a side, then 2 extra values to say if its rotated to face on the x, or y axis, z axis doesn't need one because its like that by default). Problem comes in when I try to multiply the gl_Position value by a mat4 rotation matrix to make the sides of the cube rotated properly. It doesn't even glitch out, it just doesn't display the faces at all (it does when I dont have the matrices multiplying the values).

Heres my geometry shader:

```
layout(points) in;
layout(triangle_strip, max_vertices = 4) out;

in vec3 gFacePos[];

out vec2 texCoord;

mat4 xtrans = mat4( //rotate on the x axis
1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0,
0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0
);

mat4 ytrans = mat4( //rotate on y
0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
-1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0
);

mat4 rtrans = (gFacePos[0].x * xtrans) + (gFacePos[0].y * ytrans); //figure out what the current point wants to rotate on

void main() { //this whole thing makes a square at the requested point
    gl_Position = gl_in[0].gl_Position + vec4(-0.5, 0.5, 0.0, 0.0);
    gl_Position *= rtrans; //these break it
    texCoord = vec2(0.0, 0.0);
    EmitVertex();
    gl_Position = gl_in[0].gl_Position + vec4(0.5, 0.5, 0.0, 0.0);
    gl_Position *= rtrans;
    texCoord = vec2(1.0, 0.0);
    EmitVertex();
    gl_Position = gl_in[0].gl_Position + vec4(-0.5, -0.5, 0.0, 0.0);
    gl_Position *= rtrans;
    texCoord = vec2(0.0, 1.0);
    EmitVertex();
    gl_Position = gl_in[0].gl_Position + vec4(0.5, -0.5, 0.0, 0.0);
    gl_Position *= rtrans;
    texCoord = vec2(1.0, 1.0);
    EmitVertex();
    EndPrimitive();
}
```

Fragment and vertex are pretty standard (vertex has some basic camera stuff on it).

Comment: Before reading through your code, do you simply want to rotate the cube some and then translate it somewhere so it will be visible when being rasterized?

Comment: @thokra Really I just wanted to know why this displays the squares when I don't specify a rotational matrix, but when I do it breaks. As far as I know multiplying a vector by matrix should atleast give me something rather than just a blank screen.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure but I think your matrices should be multiplied one by another. Otherwise you'll get something like
    1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 1.0, -1.0, 0.0,
    -1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.0
which scales your coordinates. They could land outside near and far clipping planes. But that is a long shot of what I deduce by reading your code.